# C# Msbuild code coverage hard halt if not met threshold

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, msbuild, nunit

We have a c# solution with more than one projects. Project uses msbuild for packaging, run Nunit for unit testing. What we don't have at the moment is to define code coverage threshold for each project and to fail msbuild if code coverage is below threshold limit. This comes out of box in java project using maven and cobertura as plug-in. 
 Any such tool in dot net world.

We are using 
- Visual Studio 2017 Professional 
- Msbuild 15.3.409.57025
- Resharper ultimate 2017.2
- DotNet Framework 4.6.2
- Nunit 2.5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ReSharper then you can use DotCover as your code coverage tool. This tool can produce a report that then can be analyzed with a build target to fail the build.

```
<Target Name="FailBuildOnLowCoverage">

    <!-- $(DotCoverResult) is the text of the report that you obtained by reading the report file -->

    <PropertyGroup>
      <CodeCoverageValue>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(DotCoverResult), '(?&lt;="Total",)(.*?)(?=[,])'))</CodeCoverageValue>
      <CodeCoverageValue Condition="'$(CodeCoverageValue)' == ''">0</CodeCoverageValue>
    </PropertyGroup>


<Message Condition="'$(CodeCoverageValue)' &lt; '30'" Text="Code coverage is less than 30%!

░░░░░░░░░░░█████████████
░░░░░░░░░███░███░░░░░░██
███░░░░░██░░░░██░██████████
████████░░░░░░████░░░░░░░██
████░░░░░░░░░░██░░██████████
████░░░░░░░░░░░███░░░░░░░░░██
████░░░░░░░░░░░██░░██████████
████░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░░░░░█
████░░░░░░░░░░░░░███░░████░░█
█████████░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░░█
███░░░░░██░░░░░░░░░░░░░█████
░░░░░░░░░███░░░░░░░██████
░░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░░░██
░░░░░░░░░░░░███░░░░░██
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██░░░░██
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░███░░░██
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██░░░█
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░█░░░█
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░██░██
░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░███
" />
```

Comment: Thanks Michael .. I will try this out.